# Creating insights from Battery monitoring parameters (State-of-charge, battery cell voltages, temperature, etc.) to use with AI or model based

Tags: lstm, prediction

So, in a new role currently and I decided to pursue the health monitoring and impending failures of batteries (Lithium Iron Phosphate, Lithium Ion and a few lead-acid as well) but having never done it before I am not so confident on my approach.

Currently what I have in mind is using the past battery data for a specific site, I would find out the variation in SOC during charging and discharging state and compare it with current day rates while alerting for large changes.

Also, if multiple batteries are connected and while discharging/ charging their SOC deviate too far from each other (standard deviation or difference in min max) I would alert that something is not right.

A bit primitive approaches but wanted something to get going.

Would love to hear from you guys' different approaches that could be used, or you guys have used in the industry.

Thanks!

PS. Let me know if you need more information.